# Apache Camel | How to achieve Chaining of routes

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a requirement to read multiple text files present in a folder. I have to read file in a specific sequence ex:- file1, then file2, then file3 and so on.

We are using Apache Camel framework (file protocol) for doing file read.

I have tried Creating one main route, which will be scheduled using a quartz scheduler. From this route, I will call multiple routes (let's call them sub-routes) as beans.

Each of these sub-routes will read a specific file from the desired folder.
I have used "file:" protocol in these sub-routes.

But here the issue is, once I trigger the main route, the sub routes keep pooling the directory on the machine. I want sub-routes to work only when called from the main-route.

How can I achieve the functionality I am targeting?

Regards
Anuj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you start the subflows when the main gets triggered and and when the final subflow is done, they simply stop themselves, hence prevent further polling.

http://camel.apache.org/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html